# ForEach cannot use branch

Tags: swiftui

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 with SwiftUI.

This code works right

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(index) of coffee.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
But the following code gives an error.

why?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
                if index == 1 {
                    Text("Cup of coffee.")
                } else {
                    Text("\(index) cups of coffee")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to
>   disambiguate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because view builder expected one return of one type view, but condition does not generate opaque return. To solve - just embed condition in Group

```
ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
  Group {
    if index == 1 {
        Text("Cup of coffee.")
    } else {
        Text("\(index) cups of coffee")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution is right, not the explanation. Actually Group has @inlinable public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) which make it possible. ForEach except just Content ... Please update your answer, it could help others to properly understand why it works.